# Global variable in ajax possible? Work around?

Tags: php, ajax, global-variables

Right now I have a website which uses PHP to generate a table from a large SQL database.

I want to add two buttons to my website which will use AJAX to update the table with new data.  The table is all indexed, so all I need is to be able to submit an "offset" variable through my XMLHttpRequest to get the new data. The code I have for that is:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","schedule_top.php?q="+offset, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Right now, my "next" button will give an offset of 3, and my "previous" button gives an offset of -3. The problem I have is if the user wants to click either button more than once. As the offset is set to 0 each time at function call, I cannot cycle beyond -3 and 3.

What should I be doing? My current AJAX code is below:

```
function loadXMLDoc(int) {
    var xmlhttp;
    var offset = 0;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {   
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('tobooth').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    if (int == 1) {
        offset -= 3;
    } else {
        offset +=3;
   }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","schedule_top.php?q="+offset, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to support IE5 and IE6? Or did you just copy-paste whatever you have found on w3schools (which is a terrible site)?

Comment: Since you defined your `offset` variabe inside the `loadXMLDoc` function, you are getting a fresh one each time it is called. Try defining it outside.

Comment: IE6 and IE7: I thought it wouldn't hurt to leave in... or is there more to it?

Comment: This is all the code I have inside my <script> </script> tags. Where else would I define it? EDIT: Wow! SO SIMPLE! THANKS!!!!

Comment: You could create a global variable by defining it outside any function; not very clean, but you don't have much code to compete for namespace.

Comment: As for having code to support IE6... aside from having no real purpose (noone uses it, Google gives you a stern warning if you visit its sites in IE7, and I guess you'll be using other stuff that IE6 or even IE7 doesn't support anyways; say `getElementsByClassName`, `querySelectorAll` or the respective library wrapper), it kinda shows where the code comes from. Use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) as your source of information. Never trust W3Schools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't answer your question directly, but I can suggest another approach.

You can create simple fields in which you will contain new offset. Or you can store offset directly on elements `next` and `prev`, e.g.

```
<a href='#' id='0' class='goPrev'>Previous</a>
```

and

```
<a href='#' id='3' class='goNext'>Next</a>
```

Default offset is zero. For next button offset will be 3, for previous null (and user can't click on prev button).

When user will click `next` button, you will do your ajax request and update both fields. goNext field will have offset 6 and previous will have offset 0.

When user will click `next` button again, you will do your ajax request again and update both fields again. goNext field will have offset 9 and previous will have offset 3.

Etc etc etc.

Also, you can store data in hidden inputs.

Hope, this will help.

Comment: Did this worked? You know, if you liked my answer you can vote up it :) Guys don't like to open questions, which had already been answered. But if it woked and you like it and will use, sure you can :)

Comment: I'm working on it still.. I cant upvote because I'm a new user and don't have enough reputation. But its definitely enough of a lead to let me start working again! Thanks!

Comment: OK. Nice that my answer helped you!